# In google cloud platform how we implement internal load balancing globally?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-cloud-networking

I am trying to find out a way for implementing regional load balancing in different regions and I want all regional load balancers under a one unicast IP address globally (internal), which is the best way to do this,
Thanks in advance

Comment: Internal load balancer are regional and in GCP there is not something like a floating IP so it Is not possible make internal global load balancing

Comment: Why do you want this unicast IP? Which feature are you looking for?

Comment: I want my internal application should have Higher Availability in case of regional failure, and fast switching Backend ( regional internal load balancer )to handle disaster recovery